Past or present participle to give the reason for an action?
I have a question related to the choice between the present and past participles. I know that both of them can be used to give the reason for an action.
So I'd like to use them to say that

the fruit was expensive, because it was imported.

The correct sentence would be:

Being imported, the fruit was expensive,

while the sentence

Imported, the fruit was expensive

would be incorrect.
So my question is, why I can't use the past participle in this sentence? Is there any difference in meaning?
Would it be the same sentence for the action which is regularly performed or for the action performed only once?
I would really appreciate all your comments.
Thank you in advance.

You need a "be" verb for the same reason you need to say "because it was imported" rather than just "because it imported".

The examples in your link are all participle phrases. Your own examples are not. Neither is very good.

In both your examples imported is an adjective.

You are using the past participle (of import). Its present participle is importing. The past participle of be is, of course, been.

OP enquired why only the present participle can be used to show the reason in this case:


The fruit was expensive, because it was imported..
Being imported, the fruit was expensive.


We can also use the past participle as an adjective. In this case the sentence would be:


The imported fruit was expensive.


I. Using the Present Participle "Being imported"

"Being imported" is a present participle phrase functioning as an adjective, modifying the noun "fruit."
This phrase highlights the state or condition of the fruit (its status as imported) and establishes a clear cause-and-effect relationship with its expensiveness.
The sentence "Being imported, the fruit was expensive" explicitly connects the fruit's imported status to the reason for its high price.

II. Using the Past Participle "Imported"

"Imported" is a past participle that also functions as an adjective, describing the fruit as something that has already been imported.
However, "The imported fruit was expensive" does not establish a causal link.
It only presents two disconnected ideas: that the fruit was imported and that it was expensive.

This lack of connection makes the past participle unsuitable for expressing the reason.
In conclusion, the present participle "Being imported" is necessary here to clarify that the fruit's expensiveness is because of its imported status, while the past participle "Imported" fails to convey this meaning.

Dear @James Mathai, thank you so much for your answer! I'd like to clarify one more point. Actually, there is an example in my link: "Worried by the news, she called the hospital." I wonder why in this case the past participle can be used to give the reason for an action, while in my own sentence "Imported, the fruit was expensive" it can't? What is the difference between these two sentences? Has it anything to do with the difference between verbal and adjectival passives?

@Ola. Yes, the difference lies in both the type of verb and the relationship between the subject and the participle.
In "Worried by the news, she called the hospital," the past participle "worried"  describes her emotional state, which provides a reason for her action.
The past participle works with stative verbs when it describes the subject's state or condition as the reason for the action. With action verbs, the participle only describes a completed process and needs additional context (e.g., "Being imported")

'Imported' can be an adjective as well as a verb. Saying "this fruit was imported" refers to the importation process it went through; saying "this fruit is imported" is describing the fruit.
In your example, the verb form is the same as the adjective, so clarity is important. "Being imported" introduces its condition as a reason for what you say next. If you just said "imported, the fruit was expensive" it sounds like the fruit is only expensive when imported - as if there is a non-imported produce that is cheaper.
